# Does Mongoid support lazy loading in similar manner Active Record does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, mongoid

I have Rails 3 project that I updated to 5, that uses Mongoind instead of Active Record. I'm trying to implement fragment caching. 
My understanding is, that with ActiveRecord, even if I have something like 
`@films = Film.all` in a controller, but never use `@films` in the view, the query won't actually run. Hence, if I cache `@films` in the view, on the second request, it'll be read from cache, and query isn't going to run. 
This is how I think ActiveRecord works.

Now to Mongoid. I cache variable in the view, but even though it's being read from cache, the query still hits db.

My question is, is there a way to avoid that with Mongoid?
Or am I missing something in terms of caching?

I tried searching online, but there isn't much on Rails Mongoid caching, not to mention, anything written after 2012.